# Why is my Stack Trace log being cut short?

Tags: c#, .net, logging, dotnet-httpclient, stack-trace

I'm using C# and target framework = .NET 4.8

I'm making a request to download images using the .net HttpClient and it works 100% on my local machine but only in 99% of cases on my test server and I'm trying to figure out why. I was originally logging to Kibana but was getting frustrated when I try and log response.StackTrace but was only getting a 2 line response that doesn't help me at all. So I've set it up to log to a file on my server but the same thing is happening. Here's the code:

```
using (StreamWriter w = File.AppendText(loggingPath + "Image Download Stack Trace.txt"))
                                {
                                    LogStackTrace(result.StackTrace, w);
                                }

public void LogStackTrace(string logMessage, TextWriter w)
    {
        w.Write("\r\nLog Entry : ");
        w.WriteLine("  :");
        w.WriteLine("  :" + logMessage);
        w.WriteLine("-------------------------------");
    }
```

There's nothing fancy going on here. The output I get is:

at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult ar)

I want more from the Stack Trace, I've tried the code above with Environment.StackTrace and I get a full dump of 50+ lines, but I don't understand why the httpResponse.StackTrace only produces the 2 line response. Please can someone explain what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: HTML has special characters and the error message probably contains these special characters.  Use following to encode the message : string = System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlEncode(string)

Comment: @jdweng thanks for your suggestion. It sounded like it could work but I'm still getting the same 2 lines

Comment: The write has to be inside the "using" block.  Outside the using block the the object is disposed.